# How to wrap strings when plotting with `text`?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a long string that I would like to add to a subplot as descriptive text.

```
description = 'This kitchen has white cabinets and two blue chairs. The upper cabinet has a black microwave. The paper towels are above the trash can. There is a black garbage can just on the left of the blue chair. On its left there is a red fire distinguisher.';
```

I have tried to add new line characters after every sentence to make it fit better.

```
subplot(1,2,2);
with_new_lines = regexprep(description, '\.', '\.\n');
text( 0.5, 0.5, with_new_lines, 'FontSize', 14', 'FontWeight', 'Bold', ...
    'HorizontalAlignment', 'Center', 'VerticalAlignment', 'middle' ) ;
```

But it still does not fit properly within the axis.

Is there a way to wrap the string dynamically to fit the subplot?

[image]

Comment: http://weknowmemes.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/fire-distinguisher.png

Comment: @gnovice I love the meme, but I plead innocent; this is a crowd sourced dataset, [SentencesNYUv2](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~fidler/projects/sentences3D.html).

Comment: @Sardar_Usama That doesn't fit the dynamically criteria

Comment: Sorry, couldn't resist. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using an annotate box, with the `FitBoxToText` property off?

```
description = 'This kitchen has white cabinets and two blue chairs. The upper cabinet has a black microwave. The paper towels are above the trash can. There is a black garbage can just on the left of the blue chair. On its left there is a red fire distinguisher.';
figure;subH=subplot(1,2,2);
pos=get(subH,'Position');
annotation('textbox', pos,...
  'String', description,...
  'FitBoxToText','off');
```

You can change the location by changing the 1st two elements of `pos` ,which (I think) describe the left-bottom corner, but forget.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`textwrap`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textwrap.html) function in one of two ways:

1. Wrap the text to fit within a text [uicontrol](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol.html):

   ```
   hText = uicontrol('Style', 'Text', 'Position', ...(some starting position)... );
   [wrappedText, newPosition] = textwrap(hText, {description});
   set(hText, 'String', wrappedText, 'Position', newPosition);
   ```
2. Wrap the text at a fixed number of columns before plotting with [`text`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html):

   ```
   wrappedText = textwrap({description}, 20);
   text(0.5, 0.5, wrappedText, 'FontSize', 14', 'FontWeight', 'Bold', ...
        'HorizontalAlignment', 'center', 'VerticalAlignment', 'middle');
   ```

Comment: It's good to know that I can use `textwrap` with `text`. I skimmed the documentation but I was focused on the discussion of uicontrols. Your solutions are definitely superior to mine, but I'm still going to award Jon the answer for a solution that is dynamic with figure resizing. Wish I could give it to both of you.

Comment: @Cecilia: If resizing happens often, I would definitely go with Jon's answer. `textwrap` is best suited for static elements, specifically uicontrols.